# Post method error using Postman app

Tags: angular, api, postman

When I make this API post Request `/posts/{id}/comments/add` :

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/45754385/comments/add?body=%20A%20comment%20Post%20test&key=**********&access_token=********&preview=true&filter=default&site=stackoverflow

I get this error:

```
{
  "error_id": 400,
  "error_message": "POST methods expects all parameters to be submitted as a form, not on the query string",
  "error_name": "bad_parameter"
}
```

any Solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So select "POST" instead of "GET" in postman and put your body to the POST body instead of address line

[image]

Comment: I have given POST and in the body what should be the key and what should be the value?

Comment: @Samson reply updated, please check the image. "key=value", so you have four key=value pairs in this sample

Comment: should i add seperators also?

Comment: @Samson no, separators is just marks that allow you see where is the key and where is the value

Comment: should i pass the same type while making post request in angular?

Comment: @Samson I hope so)) It's the idea of POST request type: address line + optional parameters in the POST body. No matter with what exact technology you send POST requests.